# Operation failed: Required 'compute.subnetworks.use' permission when creating Dataproc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-iam

I get this error when I try to create a dataproc cluster

`failed: Required 'compute.subnetworks.use' permission for ...`

Answer (score 1):

For dataproc cluster creation, this error usually occurs due to missing IAM permission when using shared VPC.

To fix this issue, please go to your shared VPC **host project** (Where your VPC network is) and grant
`Compute Network User` role to the following service accounts

1. service-[**cluster-project-number**]@dataproc-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2. the Google APIs service account,
   [**cluster-project-number**]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com

Note: The `cluster-project-number` is the project number associated with the service project (where your Dataproc cluster is provisioned).

Please check here for more information

[Dataproc IAM requirements](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/network#creating_a_cluster_that_uses_a_vpc_network_in_another_project)

[Creating a Dataproc cluster: considerations, gotchas & resources](https://medium.com/google-cloud/creating-a-dataproc-cluster-considerations-gotchas-resources-930294ddb7f3)

[Troubleshoot Dataproc error messages](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar issue but the answer above did not help sadly

What about in instances where no @dataproc-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com principal is created? Google literature says that in cases where the default ...@dataproc-accounts SA isn't created, it will use Google API's Service Agent account for the control plane SA. We have ensured it has compute network user role in both host and service projects and have given the Compute SA the same roles in both projects also, to no avail..

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/service-accounts